# A full dimensional polyhedron has at least $n+1$ vertices

Tags: convex-analysis, polyhedra, polytopes, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

I'm stuck in a property when I was reading proof of a theorem about polyhedral theory:

> Every full dimensional, bounded and non-empty polyhedron in $\mathbb R^n$ has at least $n+1$ vertices.

A vertex is a point of a polyhedron such that we cannot write it as $\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y$ such that $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

Can anyone give me a hint to prove this property?
I think I should consider the fact that this polyhedron is convex hull its vertices and with induction I should prove that convex hull of every $k$ elements is at most a $k-1$ dimensional space. But it doesn't make sense to me also these properties. Could you please help me to understand these fact truly?

Comment: Show you need $2$ points for $\mathbb{R}^1$ and then use induction on the number of dimensions.

Comment: Really, I don't know how to apply induction here. I know that every bounded polyhedron is a polytope and every polytope is convex hull of a set of vectors and if the number of these vectors is less than $n+1$ then it is contained in a hyperplane and hyperplane is not a full dimensional subset(its volume is zero). But I dont know to show that the vertices of the polyhedron is the generated set of this polytope!

Comment: Two points determine a line segment (polytope in $\mathbb{R}^1$.  If you want to make a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^2$, you need another point not on that line segment.  In this way, $3$ points determine a polytope (triangular region) in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  In order to make a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you need to add yet another point not in the triangular polytope.  And, by induction, you need at least $n+1$ points to define a polytope in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Dear Mr. Stork I think this way is not correct. For example when you have 2 points in $\mathbb R^1$ than it doesn't mean to add another point not on that line segment to have a polytope( really it is better to say bounded non empty and full dimensional polyhedron or polytope) in $\mathbb R^2$ because the first two points were not in $\mathbb R^2$. I think it is not mathematically true this way.

Comment: You can embed the $2$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and easily show that the resulting polyhedron is not "full dimensional" (as you state), and then add you additional point (properly) to show that the resulting polytope *is* full dimensional.

Comment: Yes in in $\mathbb R^2$ we can because it is understandable, but for higher dimension we cannot use this fact with dimension because we cannot imagine it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know that a polyhedron is the convex hull of its vertices, the proof can proceed like this. Suppose the vertex set is $v_1, \dots, v_m$ with $m\le n$. The vectors $v_1-v_m,\dots, v_{m-1}-v_m$ span a linear subspace $W\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension at most $m-1$. Therefore, the points $v_1, \dots, v_m$ lie in the affine subspace $W+v_m$ of dimension at most $m-1 < n$. Since $W+v_m$ is a  convex set, the convex hull of $v_1, \dots, v_m$ is contained in $W+v_m$ and therefore  has empty interior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not very familiar with this topic. Could you please introduce a book or some other sources about polyhedral theory to me to study?

Comment: Anything with "convex hull" in it, like [these notes](https://www.ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/CG10/lecture/ln2.pdf)